# Is it possible to have mocked object's method set value on reference type parameter?

Tags: c#, moq

I am using Moq to unit test a class. How can I setup the mocked IProcessor to set the Successful property on the CreateRequest parameter to true? Is this even possible? I have looked at the Callback functionality provided by the Moq framework but not sure it can do what I need in this scenario.

```
public class CreateRequest
{
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
}

public interface IProcessor()
{
    public void Process(CreateRequest createRequest);
}

public class TheClassIAmUnitTesting()
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest();
        processor.Process(createRequest);

        if (createRequest.Successful)
        {
             // do something
        }
        else
        {
             // do somethign else
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TheUnitTest()
{
    Mock<IProcessor> mock = new Mock<IProcessor>

    this.mock.setup(x=>x.Process()) //<= what do i do here to have the mock set the boolean Successful property on the CreateRequest parameter to true?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a call back and get access to the passed argument

```
[TestMethod]
public void TheUnitTest() {
    //Arrange
    Mock<IProcessor> mock = new Mock<IProcessor>();

    mock.Setup(_ => _.Process(It.IsAny<CreateRequest>()))
        .Callback((CreateRequest arg) => arg.Successful = true)
        .Verifiable();

    var subject = new TheClassIAmUnitTesting(mock.Object);

    //Act
    subject.SomeMethod();

    //Assert
    mock.VerifyAll();
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart: Callbacks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#callbacks)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
mock.Setup(x=>x.Process(It.IsAny<CreateRequest>()))
  .Callback<CreateRequest>(cr => cr.Successful = true)
```